# C: Realloc twodimensional array created by Malloc

Tags: c, arrays

I have a two-dimensional `int` array allocated as follows:

```
int **matrix = (int**)malloc(x * sizeof(int));
for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(y * sizeof(int));
```

If I do `realloc` this array by the following code

```
int **matrix = (int**)realloc(matrix, x * sizeof(int));
for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    matrix[i] = (int*)malloc((y) * sizeof(int));
```

will there be any leftover "tails" of second dimension of the array and should I use `free()` function for them before reallocating, or they will go away themselves?

Comment: There is no 2D array, nor something that can be used as one. A pointer is not an array!

Comment: `x*sizeof(int)` --> `x*sizeof(int*)`

Comment: Some of your `sizeof` expressions are wrong.  When allocating/reallocating `matrix`, you need `x*sizeof(int *)`.

Comment: [Also, do not cast the return value of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Well I can access elements of this "array" by using indexes as always (array[i][j]) and easily passing it to other functions. That is the only things I need for now. Edit: Thanks Weather Vane

Comment: That is because `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(int*)` are the same on your system. But they might not be.

Comment: Who's using 32-bit operating systems nowadays?

Comment: And yes, all of the memory allocated in the first loop will obviously be lost when you grow the array, since you don't free it and you don't reallocate it.  You have 2 choices:  (1) free it first, or (2) call `realloc` instead of `malloc` when `i` is less then the old value of `x`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala my OS is 64-bit, the compiler 32-bit.

Comment: Got it Weather Vane and Antti Haapala.

Comment: Are you trying to grow a matrix and keep existing data intact?

Comment: `int **matrix = (int**)realloc(matrix, x * sizeof(int));` would be illegal if the new `mtarix` is in the same scope as the old , and a bad idea if in a new scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will completely lose data in your `matrix`, so this is not really `realloc`ing anything; you could just as well `free` and `malloc` the top-level array, getting possibly better performance. Furthermore your code would leak memory, because the 2nd level allocations are not `free`d.

Comment: As I suspected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can resize the 2D matrix while keeping the current values intact, initializing the newly allocated cells to 0 and freeing any extra leftovers:

```
// matrix was allocated to x and y
// reallocate it to newx, newy
for (i = newx; i < x; i++) { /* free unneeded rows */
    free(matrix[i]);
}
matrix = realloc(matrix, sizeof(*matrix) * newx);
for (i = x; i < newx; i++) { /* initialize the new row pointers */
    matrix[i] = NULL;
}
for (i = 0; i < newx; i++) {
    matrix[i] = realloc(matrix[i], sizeof(*matrix[i]) * newy);
    for (int j = y; j < newy; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = 0;
}
```